# Remove null cells in join statement

Tags: mysql, join, null

```
A
|  num |   Bank   |
|   1  |   TD     |
|   2  |   BOA    |

B
|  num |   Bank   | Location |
|   1  |   TD     |    NY    |
|   2  |   BOA    |    CT    |

C
|  num |  Employee| Status |  Location |
|   1  |   John   |  Mgr   |    NY     |
|   2  |   Jacob  | Teller |    NY     |
|   3  |   Jenny  | Teller |    NY     |
|   4  |   Clark  |  Mgr   |    CT     |
|   5  |   Kent   | Teller |    CT     |


select 
a.num,
CASE
    WHEN c.status = 'Mgr' 
    Then C.employee,
CASE
    WHEN c.status = 'Teller' 
    Then C.employee,
c.location
FROM A
    JOIN B on a.num=b.num
    JOIN C on b.num=c.num
```

I'm trying get a table that shows Jacob and Jenny in 2 seperate rows with John as their manager but it shows up as this:

```
a.num | Mgr | Employee|  Location
  1   | John|  null  |    NY
  2   | null|  Jacob |    NY
  3   | null|  Jenny |    NY
```

I'd like this:

```
a.num | Mgr | Employee|  Location
  2   | John|  Jacob  |    NY
  3   | John|  Jenny  |    NY
```

Asking for more words.. ignore ..

Comment: How do you know that Jacob and Jenny have John as their manager? The `Location` field?

Comment: @egrunin yes, 1 location can only have 1 manager. I've made the edit to the table

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [Self Join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/). Basically, you need to link your table A (employee) to your Table A (mgr). I do not have access to MySQL right now, so my syntax may not work. If therE's an error just tell me and I'll fix it (or if you know the error fix it and tell me :P)

So what do you want? You want to select all of your employees.

```
Select 
    employee.num as Num, 
    'managerName' as Manager, 
    employee.Employee as Emplooyee, 
    employee.location as Location
FROM 
    C as employee
```

However, this means that you will also have managers. So you want only employees that aren't managers; you need to add `where employee.status !='Mgr'`.

This means that you have the list of all your employees and need a manager. How do you find a manager, he's an employee (C) who has the `status='Mgr'`, and is in the same bank `num` as well as `location`

So you

```
LEFT JOIN 
    C as manager 
        ON manager.location = employee.location AND
        manager.status='Mgr'
```

Which gives you a nice list of :

```
Select 
    employee.num as Num, 
    manager.Employee as Manager, 
    employee.Employee as Employee, 
    employee.location as Location
FROM 
    C as employee
LEFT JOIN 
    C as manager 
        ON manager.location = employee.location AND
        manager.status='Mgr'
WHERE employee.status !='Mgr'
```

You can remove the `WHERE` clause to list managers too, but that would mean that you have to alter the join clause to not have them be their own manager (since that's just weird). Similarly, you could also make it a [Cross] Join to list Managers without employees, or an Inner Join to filter out employees without managers (it shuldn't and will happen).

Comment: This ends up duplicating the Mgr (and total number of rows).  Is there a way I can do it through a select within a select?

Comment: Can you create an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your issue? I'm not seeing any issues when running my code with your sample data (although I'm running on SQL Server). Alternatively just edit OP with your current code, the result and the expected output.